# block my android app from install on bluestack emulator

Tags: android

I'm new to create something like that

but I wanna to stop people install my app on emulators especially bluestack.

when I googled it I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777127/block-emulators-in-android-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213326/how-to-restrict-an-apk-not-to-get-installed-in-android-emulator-simulator-but-in) but both of them failed with me and it still installing on bluestack.

tried to use [this](https://github.com/framgia/android-emulator-detector) lib too but failed

so I hope anyone help me solve this

Comment: You can't technically block it from installing, and I highly recommend you don't spend time on this. Rooting the device (emulated or otherwise) offers a huge world of APK modifications, including removing emulator detection.

Comment: but, what about Build architecture I mean  exclude x86 x86_64 from compiling in android?

Answer (score 2):

here is my idea, first why not try to check for SIM number and deny it whoever has none,

on Java:

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
```

Enable permission in `Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

If that step fails because of User Modifications on their emulators try to check if the app is running on emulator,

```
    public static boolean isEmulator() {
    return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
            || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
            || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
            || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
            || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
}
```

If `isEmulator() == true` then the app should be closed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I suggest that an `AlertDialog` pops up before closing just to tell the user why the app is being closed

Comment: Wouldn't the first one also block tablets? Seems like a horrible idea blocking an entire platform over emulator concerns.

Comment: I need it not to install. I think about exclude x86 x86_64 from compiling in android what is ur opinion in it?